# Setting Role Based Permission in code when saving new doc in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I am using Umbraco 7.2.8. When a new Document of a specific type is saved, I am hooking into the ContentService.Saved event and I want to be able to set the Public Access to only allow a specific member group access to it. Just like I would do using the Gui here.

[image]

I see in the documentation here https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Management/Services/ContentService There are a couple methods like

.AssignContentPermission(IContent content, char permission, IEnumerable userIds)

and

ReplaceContentPermissions(EntityPermissionSet permissionSet)

which both allow me to pass in a list of userIds users that have access but I am interested in setting the membership groups that have access as well as the Login Page and Error Page. How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe try asking this question on https://our.umbraco.org/ instead?

Comment: @JannikAnker Thanks tried that first but got no responses so figured I would try here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used to do it like this. I think it still applies:

```
Access.ProtectPage(false,nodeIdOfPageToProtect,loginPageNodeId,errorPageNodeId);
Access.AddMembershipRoleToDocument(nodeIdOfPageToProtect,"roleName");
```

Methods are in `umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web` so make sure you set this for your page

```
using umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web;
```

Does that help?